# Override inner element properties in React components

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have a `React` component that consists of other components and uses `semantic-ui-react`. It looks like:

```
export const RadioGroup = (props) => {
  const { value, options, label, onChange, margin, widths, ...baseProps } = props
  return (
    <InlineFormGroup margin={margin} widths={widths}>
      {/* eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/label-has-for */}
      {label && <label>{label}</label>}
      {options.map(option =>
        <BaseSemanticInput
...
```

And a plenty of stuff inside that I show by `...`. What I want is to have another component `RadioGroupVertical` that would be almost identical to the `RadioGroup` shown above except it should have `group` property on `InlineFormGroup`. I kind of do not want to copy-paste large component to do such a small edit but not sure how to do such property modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if I understood exactly but:

```
let otherProps = {};
if(baseProps && baseProps.group) {
  otherProps.group = baseProps.group;
}

<InlineFormGroup margin={margin} widths={widths} {...otherProps}>
```